# 4 divs layout (fixed-fluid-fixed-fixed) divs don't sit side-by-side

Tags: css

i need

1. 4 divs side-by-side (fixed-fluid-fixed-fixed)

the point I could arrive is here: https://jsfiddle.net/mbhndrzu/1/

it seems that `width`s are ok but they don't sit side-by-side.

May you please explain the reason what is failing & how to correct? thanks, regards

Answer (score 0):

Use flex on clearfix class to display in one line with flex:1  of inner divs to have equal widths

```
  <style>
  .clearfix
   {display:flex;
   justify-content:space-around;
   align-items: center;
  margin:auto;
    }

   .clearfix div
   { flex:1;
     justify-content:center;

    } 

</style>   



    <nav class="clearfix">
        <div id="d1">
            <p>d1</p>
            <p>hjsdakh jhsdjka hsdja sdh hjjdhsj</p>
        </div>
        <div id="d2">
            <p>d2</p>
        </div>
        <div id="d3">
            <p>d3</p>
            <p>hjsdakh</p>
            <p><img width="30" height="30" src="https://fallbacks.carbonads.com/nosvn/fallbacks/731050e6bd3fc6979e1cb1a972294dae.png" /></p>
        </div>
        <div id="d4">
            <p>
                d4
            </p>
            <p>
                d4
            </p>
        </div>
    </nav>
```

Comment: tried ur proposal in jsfiddle. not working on fluid div (d2) if it has a long paragraph. and  fluid div (d2) seems like it has a fixed width